# gym package not identifying ten-armed-bandits-v0 env

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Environment:

- Python: 3.9
- OS: Windows 10

When I try to create the ten armed bandits environment using the following code the error is thrown not sure of the reason.

```
import gym
import gym_armed_bandits

env = gym.make('ten-armed-bandits-v0')
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File D:\00_PythonEnvironments\01_RL\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py:158, in EnvRegistry.spec(self, path)
    157 try:
--> 158     return self.env_specs[id]
    159 except KeyError:
    160     # Parse the env name and check to see if it matches the non-version
    161     # part of a valid env (could also check the exact number here)

KeyError: 'ten-armed-bandits-v0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnregisteredEnv                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <module>
----> 1 env = gym.make('ten-armed-bandits-v0')

File D:\00_PythonEnvironments\01_RL\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py:235, in make(id, **kwargs)
    234 def make(id, **kwargs):
--> 235     return registry.make(id, **kwargs)

File D:\00_PythonEnvironments\01_RL\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py:128, in EnvRegistry.make(self, path, **kwargs)
    126 else:
    127     logger.info("Making new env: %s", path)
--> 128 spec = self.spec(path)
    129 env = spec.make(**kwargs)
    130 return env

File D:\00_PythonEnvironments\01_RL\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py:203, in EnvRegistry.spec(self, path)
    197     raise error.UnregisteredEnv(
    198         "Toytext environment {} has been moved out of Gym. Install it via `pip install gym-legacy-toytext` and add `import gym_toytext` before using it.".format(
    199             id
    200         )
    201     )
    202 else:
--> 203     raise error.UnregisteredEnv("No registered env with id: {}".format(id))

UnregisteredEnv: No registered env with id: ten-armed-bandits-v0
```

When I check the environments available, I am able to see it there.

```
from gym import envs
print(envs.registry.all())

dict_values([EnvSpec(CartPole-v0), EnvSpec(CartPole-v1), EnvSpec(MountainCar-v0), EnvSpec(MountainCarContinuous-v0), EnvSpec(Pendulum-v1), EnvSpec(Acrobot-v1), EnvSpec(LunarLander-v2), EnvSpec(LunarLanderContinuous-v2), EnvSpec(BipedalWalker-v3), EnvSpec(BipedalWalkerHardcore-v3), EnvSpec(CarRacing-v0), EnvSpec(Blackjack-v1), EnvSpec(FrozenLake-v1), EnvSpec(FrozenLake8x8-v1), EnvSpec(CliffWalking-v0), EnvSpec(Taxi-v3), EnvSpec(Reacher-v2), EnvSpec(Pusher-v2), EnvSpec(Thrower-v2), EnvSpec(Striker-v2), EnvSpec(InvertedPendulum-v2), EnvSpec(InvertedDoublePendulum-v2), EnvSpec(HalfCheetah-v2), EnvSpec(HalfCheetah-v3), EnvSpec(Hopper-v2), EnvSpec(Hopper-v3), EnvSpec(Swimmer-v2), EnvSpec(Swimmer-v3), EnvSpec(Walker2d-v2), EnvSpec(Walker2d-v3), EnvSpec(Ant-v2), EnvSpec(Ant-v3), EnvSpec(Humanoid-v2), EnvSpec(Humanoid-v3), EnvSpec(HumanoidStandup-v2), EnvSpec(FetchSlide-v1), EnvSpec(FetchPickAndPlace-v1), EnvSpec(FetchReach-v1), EnvSpec(FetchPush-v1), EnvSpec(HandReach-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateZ-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateZTouchSensors-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateZTouchSensors-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateParallel-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateParallelTouchSensors-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateParallelTouchSensors-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateXYZ-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateXYZTouchSensors-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateXYZTouchSensors-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockFull-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlock-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockTouchSensors-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockTouchSensors-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggRotate-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggRotateTouchSensors-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggRotateTouchSensors-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggFull-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEgg-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggTouchSensors-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggTouchSensors-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenRotate-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenRotateTouchSensors-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenRotateTouchSensors-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenFull-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePen-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenTouchSensors-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenTouchSensors-v1), EnvSpec(FetchSlideDense-v1), EnvSpec(FetchPickAndPlaceDense-v1), EnvSpec(FetchReachDense-v1), EnvSpec(FetchPushDense-v1), EnvSpec(HandReachDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateZDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateZTouchSensorsDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateZTouchSensorsDense-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateParallelDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateParallelTouchSensorsDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateParallelTouchSensorsDense-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateXYZDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateXYZTouchSensorsDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockRotateXYZTouchSensorsDense-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockFullDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockTouchSensorsDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateBlockTouchSensorsDense-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggRotateDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggRotateTouchSensorsDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggRotateTouchSensorsDense-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggFullDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggTouchSensorsDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulateEggTouchSensorsDense-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenRotateDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenRotateTouchSensorsDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenRotateTouchSensorsDense-v1), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenFullDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenTouchSensorsDense-v0), EnvSpec(HandManipulatePenTouchSensorsDense-v1), EnvSpec(CubeCrash-v0), EnvSpec(CubeCrashSparse-v0), EnvSpec(CubeCrashScreenBecomesBlack-v0), EnvSpec(MemorizeDigits-v0), EnvSpec(three-armed-bandits-v0), EnvSpec(five-armed-bandits-v0), EnvSpec(ten-armed-bandits-v0), EnvSpec(MultiarmedBandits-v0)])
```

Comment: Hi @Bonson, have you made `pip install -e .` after installing the `gym_armed_bandits` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a problem with your Python version: [k-armed-bandits](https://github.com/diegoalejogm/openai-k-armed-bandits) library was made 4 years ago, when Python 3.9 didn't exist. Besides this, the [configuration files in the repo](https://github.com/diegoalejogm/openai-k-armed-bandits/blob/master/.python-version) indicates that the Python version is 2.7 (not 3.9).

If you create an environment with Python 2.7 and follow the setup instructions it works correctly on Windows:

```
git clone gym_armed_bandits
cd gym_armed_bandits
pip install -e .
```

Comment: I somehow missed this. It worked on Python 3.9 as well. Need to see if all the functionalities work as required. Thank you for this.